# Persistent memory cache for Windows Applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, caching, memorycache

I'm looking for an in-memory cache that persists even after the windows forms application is closed. So far, the only option I've considered is to use a binary formatter to write the memory cache object to a file before closing the application.

Is there a persistent memory cache available over NuGet that I can use?

EDIT:
We have about 30 million rows in a "mapping" table that needs to be queried about 100,000 times every 1 hour. The idea behind needing a cache was to avoid piling up the database with queries.

Structure of the mapping table:

```
Zip code             TimeZoneGMTOffset
---------------------------------------
12345                -6
12346                -5
...
```

We will have about 100,000 profiles that we'll be parsing every hour. As a part of this parsing, we'll query timezone offset against their zip code and use it to calculate a time range.

What'd be the best way to do that?

Comment: As "search for tools" this likely to be closed as off-topic. You may want to clarify why you need something like MemCacheD for your WinForms app... There may be easier ways to solve original issue (unless you trying to point fingers to someone else when "my app uses too much memory" comes up).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [`PersistentDictionary`](https://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PersistentDictionaryDocumentation&referringTitle=Documentation) that comes bundled with `ManagedEsent`. It's actually a managed wrapper over Esent.

It's as easy to use as a `Dictionary<K, V>`. Persistence is done behind the scenes.

You will need to structure you data to be cached in a key-value-pair format. Values are also subjected to some conditions. See the `Supported Value Types` section in the page I linked.

Features (from their CodePlex page):

1. No setup: the ESENT database engine is part of Windows and requires no setup. EsentCollections will work on any version of Windows from XP onwards.
2. Performance: ESENT supports a high rate of updates and retrieves. Write-ahead logging decreases the cost of making small updates to the data. Information is inserted into or retrieved from the database in-process so data access has very low overhead. B-trees give O(log n) access to data by key and the records are stored in sorted order.
3. Simplicity: a PersistentDictionary looks and behaves like the .NET Dictionary/SortedDictionary/SortedList classes. No extra method calls are required.
4. Administration-free: ESENT automatically manages the database cache size, transaction logfiles, and crash recovery so no database administration is needed. The code is structured so that there are no deadlocks or conflicts, even when multiple threads use the same dictionary. ESENT runs in-process and doesn’t expose any network access, providing a high degree of security.
5. Reliability: ESENT’s write-ahead logging system means that a database is automatically recovered after a process crash or unexpected machine shutdown (e.g. power outage). Database transactions are used to ensure the logical consistency of the database.
6. Concurrency: each data structure can be accessed by multiple threads. Reads are non-blocking and updates to different items in the collection are allowed to proceed concurrently.
7. Scale: A collection can contain up to 2^31 objects, and values can be up to 2GB in size. The maximum database size is 16TB .